# Understand interface Map<K,V>

Tags: java, dictionary

I am learning map datastructure know, I have trouble understand the `entrySet() Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>` within the map interface. **Is this supposed to be a nested self referenced ?** For reference, this is an excerpt from the definition of the `java.util.Map<K,V>` interface:

```
public interface Map<K,V> {
    Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I hope you enjoy learning java but please refer to the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic before asking

Comment: thanks, I will make sure that I follow the rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this supposed to be a nested self referenced ?

No. It only says that whatever a `Map` returns as the result of this method must be an object instance which obeys the `Set` interface, which reflects the contents of this `Map`'s entries. It is the same with `.keySet()`.

It makes sense that both are `Set`s, since entries in a `Map` are unique ([as a result of the defined contract for `Map.Entry`'s `.equals()`/`.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)), and so are keys (but for keys, *you* are responsible of ensuring that `.equals()`/`.hashCode()` is respected).

HOWEVER, you have to be careful. For both of these methods, the javadoc says:

> The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa.

And this can spell trouble if you are not careful.

Look at this example:

```
public static void main(final String... args)
{
    final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("hello", "world");
    map.put("foo", "bar");

    // Create a map entry
    final Map.Entry<String, String> entry
        = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("foo", "bar");

    // Remove it from the set
    map.entrySet().remove(entry);
    System.out.println("after removing entry: " + map);

    // Remove a key
    map.keySet().remove("hello");
    System.out.println("after removing key: " + map);
}
```

Result:

```
after removing entry: {hello=world}
after removing key: {}
```

Comment: Thank you. So Map.Entry<String, String> represents a combination of key and value. Also I came cross an implementation of map called "WeakHashMap", it uses a "weak reference" (So I guess it is not strong typed, some kind of casting involved ?). Do you have any knowledge regarding this?

Comment: Uhno, I only know that there are strong, soft, weak and phantom references, and while I have read literature a little all over the place concerning these, I still cannot really figure out what their real use is :/

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>
```

The type above means: a set of map entries. `Map.Entry` is an interface nested inside the `Map` interface. There is no self-reference involved, but the type of the set returned from `entrySet` reuses the `<K,V>` type bindings of the containing map.

A *map entry* is the pair (key, value), and the whole map is conceptually just a set of map entries. This view of the map is ideal for the use case of *iterating* over the complete contents of the map, but is not well-suited for retrieval by key, which is the main use case for the map.